# complex numbers -equation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

$z,w \in \mathbb{C}, z \neq 0, w \neq 0. $ It's known also that $zw \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $w = a\overline z$ when $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

I tried to solve it as follows:

$z = (a+ib), w=(c+id).$

$zw \in \mathbb{R}$ than:

$zw = (a+ib)(c+id) = ac - bd + i (ad + cb)$

than $ad+cb = 0$.

but how can I continue from here to prove that $w = a\overline z$?

Comment: $$\frac{w}{\bar z}=\frac{zw}{z\bar z}=\frac{zw}{|z|^2}$$

Comment: @mathlove That's an overpowered answer! +1

Comment: @mathlove not sure who got there first. :-p

Comment: @zainpatel Don't worry you got a +1 from me too. I doubt one of you copied the other's answer since it seems the time difference between your posts is of some seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $zw = b$ for some $b \in \mathbb{R}$ hence $$w = \frac{b}{z} = \frac{b\overline{z}}{z\overline{z}} = \frac{b\overline{z}}{|z|^2}$$

Then labelling $a = \frac{b}{|z|^2} \in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$w = \frac{b\overline{z}}{|z|^2} = a\overline{z}$$ as required.

Comment: In the last part you ment $w = a \overline z$ and not $ zw = a \overline z $ ?

Comment: Yes, I meant $w = a\overline{z}$, corrected, thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.

I will, however, make a slight alteration to your work so that "$a$" does not appear twice in the proof.

Let $z = (p+iq), w=(r+is).$

$zw = (p+iq)(r+is) = pr - qs + i (ps + qr)$

If $zw \in \mathbb{R}$ then $Im(zw)=0 \Rightarrow ps+qr = 0$.

Rearrange to make $ps=-qr \Rightarrow s=-\frac {qr}p$

$w=r+is=r-i\frac {qr}p$

$w=\frac rp (p-iq)=a (p-iq)=a \overline z $

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exponential expression of complex numbers:

$$z=r_1e^{i\theta_1}\land w=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$$

$$zw=r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}\in\mathbb{R}\Leftrightarrow\theta_1+\theta_2\equiv0\mod{2\pi}$$

Thus: $$\theta_2\equiv-\theta_1\mod{2\pi}$$

Hence $$w=r_2e^{-i\theta_2}=\frac{r_2}{r_1}\bar{z}$$